# dotnet restore on Travis

Tags: c#, .net-core, travis-ci, xunit

I have a microservices based application within one solution but it has several projects - 5 exactly.
I have some xUnit tests that I’d like to build on Travis CI, however I’m getting `The command "dotnet restore" failed and exited with 1 during` error.
This is my very first time working with Travis.

My travis.yml file

```
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 3.1.202
sudo: required

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install nuget
install:
  - dotnet restore
branches:
    only:
     - Testing

script:
 - dotnet build
 - dotnet test TestCore/TestCore.csproj"
```

The output on Travis:

```
Installing .NET Core

0.00s
git.checkout

0.71s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=Testing https://github.com/NagyDominik/OnlineRetailer_Partial.git NagyDominik/OnlineRetailer_Partial

0.01s

0.11s$ dotnet --info

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):

 Version:   3.1.202

 Commit:    6ea70c8dca

Runtime Environment:

 OS Name:     ubuntu

 OS Version:  16.04

 OS Platform: Linux

 RID:         ubuntu.16.04-x64

 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.202/

Host (useful for support):

  Version: 3.1.4

  Commit:  0090613580

.NET Core SDKs installed:

  3.1.202 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:

  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

before_install

17.04s$ sudo apt-get install nuget

$ dotnet restore

Welcome to .NET Core 3.1!

---------------------

SDK Version: 3.1.202

----------------

Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs

Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core

Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new

Learn about the installed HTTPS developer cert: https://aka.ms/aspnet-core-https

Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs

Write your first app: https://aka.ms/first-net-core-app

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

More than one project or solution file.

The command "dotnet restore" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

Any suggestion is very welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your github project has multiple project/solution files in the main directory:

- `OnlineRetailer.sln`
- `docker-compose.dcproj`

If you have multiple project or solution files in the main directory of the project, `dotnet build` can get confused and wont know what to build.

You just need to tell `dotnet build` what you want to build. For example:

```
- dotnet build OnlineRetailer.sln
```

As an aside, I think you dont need this at all:

```
sudo apt-get install nuget
```

The SDK is self-contained and contains the nuget pieces it needs to do `dotnet restore`.

Comment: Oh, what a "duh" moment. This is definitely the solution to my problem. Thank you Omair for your help!